# How to stop ´enumerateChildNodesWithName("//*") ´ enumeration?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, enumeration, treenode, sknode

How do I stop this enumeration? I have the following code and Xcode complaining that I cannot assign a value to let constant. Stopping is probably a simple thing but I'm quite the noobie with Swift, so please bear with me.

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("//*") {
        spaceshipNode, stop in
        if (( spaceshipNode.name?.hasSuffix("ship") ) != nil) {
            for enemyNode in self.children {
                if (enemyNode.name == "enemy"){
                    if(enemyNode.containsPoint(spaceshipNode.position)){
                        self.gotoGameOverScene(spaceshipNode)
                        stop = true // Error: Cannot assign to value: 'stop' is a 'let' constant
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally you'd better show your code as text. With which we can easily copy & paste, and test it, or edit it.

In your code, the type of `stop` should be shown as `UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>` in the Quick Help pane of Xcode.

You need to modify the content of the pointer, in Swift2:

```
            stop.memory = true
```

---

In Swift 3, the property `memory` is renamed to `pointee`:

```
            stop.pointee = true
```

Comment: what about swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483024-enumeratechildnodes) suggests that we stop enumeration via `stop.initialize(to: true)`.